# Find any word of a list in the column of dataframe

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, contains

I have a list of words `negative` that has 4783 elements. I want to use the following code

```
tweets3 = tweets2[tweets2['full_text'].str.contains('|'.join(negative))]
```

But, it gives ane error like this `error: multiple repeat at position 4193`.

I do not understand this error. Apparently, if I use a single word in `str.contains` such as `str.contains("deal")` I am able to get results.

All I need is a new dataframe that carries only those rows which carry any of the words occuring in the dataframe `tweets2` column `full_text`.

As a matter of choice I would also like to see if I can have a `boolean` column for present and absent values as `0 or 1`.

I arrived at using the following code with the help of @wp78de:

`tweets2['negative'] = tweets2.loc[tweets2['full_text'].str.contains(r'(?:{})'.format('|'.join(negative)), regex=True, na=False)].copy()`

Comment: Maybe `.str.contains(r'(?:{})'.format('|'.join(words)), regex=True, na=False)]`

Comment: finally figured out what went wrong. Out of 4783 elements of negative words some were spelt like `f**k, bull****, ***hole` and these created problems for the `regex` to work.

Comment: thanks! to all who spared their valuable time.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arbitrary literal strings that may have regular expression metacharacters in it you can use the `re.escape()` function. Something along this line should be sufficient:

```
.str.contains(r'(?:{})'.format(re.escape('|'.join(words)), regex=True, na=False)]
```